# What should I use "can" or "could"?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, irrealis-mood

I am stucking at "can" and "could" definition in my words sentence.What should i use?

[Like ebay Auction rule]

1.You are responsible to pay the charges within 7 days after won.
  If not,you couldn't bid on our auction and you could bid after payment has been completed.

2.You are responsible to pay the charges within 7 days after won.
  If not,you can't bid on our auction and you can bid after payment has been completed.

Which one was right to take?If so,please explain about why should i use this?

Thank you.Any help?

Comment: I would use "can't" (because "couldn't" doesn't even make any sense). I would also put whitespaces after commas, periods, and question marks (because in English, and *all* languages using the Latin alphabet, you must put whitespaces after commas, periods, and question marks).

Comment: You also should say "When should I use ..."

Comment: Isn't (2) is obviously the correct sentence because of the tenses?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are clunky, as you can't "bid" after you've paid someone.

I think a better way of saying it is:

Once you have won an auction, you must pay within 7 days of the auction closing. 
If you have not paid for your order within 7 days of the auction closing, your order will be cancelled.